# Android Studio start view resolution problem in Ubuntu

Tags: android-studio, ubuntu

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 on an FHD monitor with 1920x1080 resolution but I am getting this type of Android Studio start view. It's not properly adjusting the content within the screen.

[image]

If I try to resize the view, I get this.

[image]

Comment: I am facing the same issue on my Ubuntu 20.04. Any solutions so-far? 
I tried changing my openJDK to OracleJDK and re-installed android-studio. Still no luck.

Answer (score 0):

You should access System Settings -> Display. There you'll see a Resolution drop-down menu. Just click on it and check the resolution you desire, like 1600x900. Then, just click Apply and you should see the changes.

Comment: Currently, I am using 1920x1080 resolution. I even tried 1600x900 but in vain.

Comment: Maybe you must ask your question in [Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/).

Answer (score 0):

I was having the same issue with my Android-Studio on my Ubuntu 20.04.

I was able to fix it by changing the dpi settings in `~/.Xresources` file from **180** to **96**.

```
Xft.dpi: 96
Xft.antialias: true
Xft.hinting: true
Xft.rgba: rgb
Xft.autohint: true
Xft.hintstyle: hintfull
Xft.lcdfilter: lcdfilter
```

Make sure to reboot your machine after the changes.

Answer (score 0):

Try adding `hidpi=false` to the file `<android studio root folder>/bin/idea.properties`.

More info here  [Troubleshoot Android Studio](https://developer.android.com/studio/troubleshoot.html#high-density)
.